# php use object property value as variable variable name

Tags: php

I'm trying to make a wrapper class for the primitive types in php but I encountered a problem while making a 'string' class;

If a create a new class like `$str = new _string();` it would be nice if i could still assign the value with `$str = 'foo';` but of course that will overwrite `$str` and the class will be destroyed.

So I had the (possibly crazy) idea of accessing the class with `$str` and its value with `$$str` by creating `$$str` in the global scope when instantiating `$str`

The problem is `global $$this->name` doesn't work as I'd expect, infact I'm not quite sure whats going on.

```
class _string {

    private $name;

    public function __construct($name) {
        $this->name = 'str_' . $name;     
        global $$this->name;         // <---this doesn't work properly   
        $strName = 'str_' . $name;        //assigning a global variable variable
        global $$strName;                 //from a local variable works fine   
    }

    public function __toString() {
        return $this->name;
    }

    public function rev() {
        $strName = $this->name;
        global $$strName;
        $$strName=strrev($$strName);
        $$this->name=strrev($$this->name);
    }                         //       ^
                              //       |
}                             //       |
                              //       |
$str = new _string('str');    //       |
$$str = 'hello';              //       |
$str->rev();    //Warning: Attempt to assign property of non-object 
echo $$str;     //olleh
```

My aim is to avoid using `$str->value='foo'` and get as close to `$str='foo'` as possible

Is this even possible? Or does anyone have a better suggestion?

Comment: TL;DR but I think you have some missing brackets: `$$this->name` -- ``${$this->name}``

Comment: You're aiming to treat a string primitive like an object with methods?

Comment: Nikic has a [good recent post about this](http://nikic.github.io/2014/03/14/Methods-on-primitive-types-in-PHP.html) in the future of PHP... (not that it solves what you're trying to do here)

Comment: @MichaelBerkowski so in essence the aim is to get as close to `$str = new _string()`, `$str ='foo';`,`$str->rev();`, `echo $str // oof` as possible

Comment: And [ircmaxell's original contrasting viewpoint](http://blog.ircmaxell.com/2014/03/an-opinion-on-future-of-php.html)...

Comment: @ÁlvaroG.Vicario That totally Worked! you should post as an answer.

Comment: http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.variables.variable.php `The variable $this is also a special variable that cannot be referenced dynamically.`

Comment: @MichaelBerkowski thanks for the references

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This:

```
$$a->b
```

... means:

1. Take variable `$a`
2. Cast to string
3. Use the string to call the variable with that name
4. Read property `b`

Since `$a` (in your case `$this`) is an object, it feels like a bug. You possibly want:

```
${$this->name}
```